# discord.py embed help command with reaction pages

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a help command with multiple pages that you can go back and forth with using reactions. It works properly but when you get to page 2 and go forward again, Nothing happens.
Same when you go to page 1 and try to go back. How can I make it so when you try to go past the last page it goes back to the first page and when you try to go before the first page, it takes you to the last page?

```
@client.hybrid_command(name = "help", with_app_command=True, description="Get a list of commands")
@commands.guild_only()
async def help(ctx):
    pages = 2
    cur_page = 1
    roleplayembed = discord.Embed(color=embedcolor, title="Roleplay Commands")
    roleplayembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Cuddle", value="Cuddle a user and add a message(Optional)",inline=False)
    roleplayembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Hug", value="Hug a user and add a message(Optional)",inline=False)
    roleplayembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Kiss", value="Kiss a user and add a message(Optional)",inline=False)
    roleplayembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Slap", value="Slap a user and add a message(Optional)",inline=False)
    roleplayembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Pat", value="Pat a user and add a message(Optional)",inline=False)
    roleplayembed.set_footer(text=f"Page {cur_page} of {pages}")
    roleplayembed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    basicembed = discord.Embed(color=embedcolor, title="Basic Commands")
    basicembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Waifu", value="Posts a random AI Generated Image of a waifu",inline=False)
    basicembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}8ball", value="Works as an 8 ball",inline=False)
    basicembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Ara", value="Gives you a random ara ara from Kurumi Tokisaki",inline=False)
    basicembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Wikipedia", value="Search something up on the wiki",inline=False)
    basicembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Userinfo", value="Look up info about a user",inline=False)
    basicembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Ask", value="Ask the bot a question",inline=False)
    basicembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Askwhy", value="Ask the boy a question beginning with 'why'",inline=False)
    basicembed.add_field(name=f"{client.command_prefix}Avatar", value="Get a user's avatar or your own avatar",inline=False)
    basicembed.set_footer(text=f"Page {cur_page+1} of {pages}")
    basicembed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    contents = [roleplayembed, basicembed]
    message = await ctx.send(embed=contents[cur_page-1])
        
    # getting the message object for editing and reacting

    await message.add_reaction("◀️")
    await message.add_reaction("▶️")

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["◀️", "▶️"]
        # This makes sure nobody except the command sender can interact with the "menu"

    while True:
        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60, check=check)
            # waiting for a reaction to be added - times out after x seconds, 60 in this
            # example

            if str(reaction.emoji) == "▶️" and cur_page != pages:
                cur_page += 1
                await message.edit(embed=contents[cur_page-1])
                await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

            elif str(reaction.emoji) == "◀️" and cur_page > 1:
                cur_page -= 1
                await message.edit(embed=contents[cur_page-1])
                await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

            else:
                await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
                # removes reactions if the user tries to go forward on the last page or
                # backwards on the first page
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await message.delete()
            break
            # ending the loop if user doesn't react after x seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid repetition, in your loop:

```
while True:

    try:
        reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60, check=check)
        # waiting for a reaction to be added - times out after x seconds, 60 in this
        # example

        if str(reaction.emoji) == "▶️":
            cur_page += 1
            

        elif str(reaction.emoji) == "◀️": 
            cur_page -= 1

        if cur_page > pages: #check if forward on last page
          cur_page = 1 
        elif cur_page < 1: #check if back on first page
          cur_page = pages 
        await message.edit(embed=contents[cur_page-1])
        await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

        
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await message.delete()
        break
```